# How to build a predictive dialer?

Tags: asterisk, voip

I need to build a reliable predictive dialer based on Asterisk. Currently the system we use includes Wombat and Asterisk, and we do not find this solution usable as Wombat provides a poor API and it's impossible to use it without regular manual operations.

The system we want:

- Can be used solely via API or direct database queries (adding lists to campaigns, updating lists, starting campaigns, stopping campaigns etc.) so that it can be completely integrated into an existing product
- Is free, or paid for annually independent to the usage rate
- Is considered stable
- Should be able to handle tens of thousands of calls per day, if it matters

Answer (score 2):

Use vicidial.org or hire freelancer to build new core with your needed api.

Comment: Will try that, thanks. Will be back when we verify that it fits our needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can also check OSdial for this, it also developed using asterisk.

Answer (score 0):

We have been working with a preview of the next version of Wombat, through the Early Access program, and Wombat has a complete configuration and reporting JSON API and you can deploy it "headless" in order to scale up to thousands of parallel lines. If you ask Loway they can likely get you access to the Early Access program.

BTW, Vicidial is great for agent-based outbound, but imposes quite a large penalty on the number of agents per server - you cannot reasonably use it to do telecasting at the scale we are looking for as it would require too many servers. Wombat is leaner and can drive over one thousands channel per server. YMMV.

Answer (score -2):

This question would be better placed on a "hire-a-freelancer" site like [oDesk](https://www.odesk.com/companies/JKL-Group-Agency_~01085d020d7762be4a) ... if you need custom programing done, those are the sorts of places to go to get manpower.

Your specifications are well within what is possible with Asterisk.  I'd strongly recommend looking at Vici Dial and OS Dial as others have suggested;  out of the can, they are pretty good.

The hard part of any auto-dialer is not the dialer, oddly enough.  It's the prediction algorithms, the answering machine detection algorithms and the agent UI.  Those are what makes or breaks an auto-dialer application for a company.

Comment: You misunderstood, I am a developer myself and don't ask for any coding help. What I want is an advice on possible solutions, like Vicidial or OSdial, which helped as I did not manage to find those using Google before. And I understand that predictive dialing is a feature above dialing itself, but you're talking about it like everyone has to invent it for themselves rather than configure an existing software like Vicidial.

Comment: You asked your question on a programing related website.  Not a seeking-software related website.  Thus, I presumed you were asking a question about programing your own software.

Comment: True, I just don't know any seeking-software website.